# Analyzer option for using const

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there an analyzer option I can use in `analysis_options.yaml` that will notify me when I could use the `const` keyword? It would be nice to be notified about all the places in my code where I can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few dartanalyzer lints related to `const`:

- [prefer_const_constructors](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html)
- [prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables.html)
- [prefer_const_declarations](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_declarations.html)
- [prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables.html)

Also:

- [unnecessary_const](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_const.html)

You can see [the full list of supported lint rules](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `prefer_const_constructors`